# Intel XDK 1332 Cordova 3.3 Unexpected Build Error

Tags: android, html, cordova, intel-xdk, build-error

I was making an app and constantly making builds of it to test it out on my phone and everything was working very well. I have been making this app for a little over a week now. It has been finished but I am having a big problem. I can export it as a Firefox app and a legacy hybrid Android app, but not a Cordova Android app. This is weird because just the other day I was making Cordova Android builds, though this did happen before and I think that I just went to sleep and woke up and it had been fixed (I don't remember). Anyway, Here is the build error I am getting:

The build failed. An error occurred while building the application. Verify your build assets are correct and try again.

```
Build Log:
Building a Cordova 3.3 application.
The application name is "TheFormula_Solver"
The package name is "com.megabyteraingmail.com.theformulasolver"
Plugin "Connection" (org.apache.cordova.network-information) installed.
Plugin "Device" (org.apache.cordova.device) installed.
Plugin "Events (battery status)" installed.
Plugin "Admob" installed.
Plugin "Base" (intel.xdk.base) installed.
Updated "minSdkVersion" with "10"
Updated "android:screenOrientation" to "portrait"
Updated "versionCode" to "1"
Updated "versionName" to "1.0.0"
Updated "debuggable" to "false"
Installed ldpi launch icon
Installed mdpi launch icon
Installed hdpi launch icon
Installed xhdpi launch icon
An unexpected error occured while attempting to build the application.
```

Here is my android xml file:

[image: config xml file]

Here are my build settings:

[image: Build Settings]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't read the micro-print in your images, but did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: @JeremyMiller You can right-click and press view image for the enlarged view with clearer text. How do I clean the project?

Answer (score 0):

`Target Android Version` is missing.

Add target android version as `19` and build.

(Sorry the build error message is not very clear, we are working on adding detailed log that tells exactly what went wrong.)

Comment: It still fails. I have built other applications with that blank and they worked fine.

Comment: can u try removing spaces in app name and also all lowercase?